# C# Form: Open Comand Prompt and type in Codes won't work

Tags: c#, forms, console

I have a simple Windows Form Application in C#, my Problem is I can't open an command Prompt and type in any codes.
In the command prompt I would navigate to `"C:\adb\adb.exe"` and then hit enter with `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");` but I can't

Any help (Is that even possible?)

Comment: To run `cmd` and pass arguments, try this. `var command = "you command here";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",command);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var commandText = "C:\adb\adb.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", commandText);
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

There are ways as well to run a shell command and hide the window as well but, this is the answer to what you have asked.

I cannot recommend enough that you dig into the `System.Diagnostics` and `System.Diagnostics.Process` namespaces.  You can find more information on them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics(v=vs.118).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics(v=vs.118).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok thanks for answering and sure I have hided my command promp ;)

Comment: You are most welcome.  If this helped, please up vote and mark it as your answer.

Comment: :( It don't works when I try this code the command prompt opens nonstop I think because of it only hits ENTER. In the command line not `C:\adb\adb.exe´ is displayed but `C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop\Root\Root\bin\Debug>´ :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the cmd window gets focus from the sendkeys, and that you send the right keys:

```
SendKeys.Send(@"C:\adb\adb.exe");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

You can also write it as a batch file, run it and delete it afterwards.